# What's the standard config file name and extension in Python?

Tags: python, config, filenames, file-extension

I'm creating a config file to hold configuration/properties settings for my project that frequently change, such as file paths. What's the standard name/extension for such a file? (e.g. in Java I've used config.xml, in VB.NET I've used App.config...)

Comment: it's worth considering to use YAML (`.yaml` or `.yml`) configuration files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, consider using ConfigParser (configparser in 3.0, so the documentation says).  That doesn't solve the naming problem, but it is a readable alternative to xml for most configuration needs.

Whatever name you use, make all the parts meaningful. I would probably use something like appName.cfg, where appName identifies your application, or the part of the application the configuration is for.

Comment: Thanks! I am planning on using ConfigParser, was just wondering if there are any accepted or widely used naming conventions for the file

Answer (score 13):

Ok, I've asked around where I work and researched a little, and this is what I've come up with as suggestions:

- settings.ini
- applicationName.config
- applicationName.cfg

If anyone has any other suggestions, feel free to add...

Answer (score 4):

The docs seem to use `.cfg`

On Windows, many people (such as mercurial) use `.ini`

Comment: The [configparser docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) for Python 3 now use `.ini` in all examples except the "Legacy API Examples" (which use `.cfg`)